# Detect Touch in Base Class

Tags: ios, swift, timer, session-management, user-inactivity

In my application i want to do a `session timeout` after some time of `inactivity`. But if the user interacts with the app the `timer` needs to be reset.

Main concern is this should be implemented in part of the application not for the whole application, so is there any alternative for subclassing `UIApplication` to detect `user interaction`.

I do have a base class for those particular controller but `touch or gesture delegates` are not getting called in base class.

How can I detect user interaction for few controllers.

Thanks in advance for any ideas and help.

Comment: Can you please add some code? how you structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out a way. In my base class, I was setting tap gesture on view earlier.

```
    let tap =  UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
    tap.delegate = self
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

so instead of `view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)` now I am adding gesture on `window`

```
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        window.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

and I implemented `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool { 
 // My Code here
   return true
}
```

So, Now my base class is able to detect any taps and calling the `delegate`.

**Please Note:** Adding this `delegate/ gesture` is not effecting the touch or gesture on any of the other views of my child classes.